# Matlab code for $y_{n+2} - y_n = h\left[(1/3)f_{n+2} + (4/3)f_{n+1} + (1/3)f_n\right]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, newton-raphson

I am looking for a Matlab code for the $2$ stage multistep method : 
$$y_{n+2} - y_n = h\left[(1/3)f_{n+2} + (4/3)f_{n+1} + (1/3)f_n\right]$$
Note that $f_n = f(x_n,y_n)$. Now, since $f_{n+2} = f(x_{n+2},y_{n+2})$ and $y_{n+2}$ is also the output of the method, cleary this is an **implicit** method. That means that Newton-Raphson shall be used for the calculation of the final output. The point of that code is to use it in a paper-work I am assembling for some conclusions over methods. Theoritically, I have proven that this is a method of order $4$, meaning that : $|T_n| \leq ch^4$. I want to prove this experimentally by using a certain method, but this can't be done if I do not have the code for the given method.

Since I am not that good in programming, I am kindly requesting some help regarding the code. I would really appreciate any elaborated algorithm. Thanks in advance !

My attempt at a code using the rk4 function already defined for the first steps :

```
function [tout, yout] = newcorrect(FunFcn,t0,tfinal,step,y0)
maxiter = 1000;
tolnr   = 1e-9;
diffdelta = 1e-6;
stages=2;
[tout,yout]=rk4(FunFcn,t0,t0+(stages-1)*step,step,y0);
tout=tout(1:stages);
yout=yout(1:stages);
t = tout(stages);
y = yout(stages).';
% The main loop
 while abs(t- tfinal)> 1e-6 
    if t + step > tfinal, step = tfinal - t; end
    t = t + step;
    yn0 = y;
    ynf = yn0;
    yn = inf;
    iter = 0;
    while (abs(yn - ynf)>= tolnr) && (iter < maxiter)
        df = 1/diffdelta * (feval(FunFcn,t, yn0+diffdelta) - feval(FunFcn, t, yn0));
        yn = yn0 - 1/(1/3*step*df - 1) * (4/3*step*feval(FunFcn,tout(end),yout(end)) + 1/3*step*feval(FunFcn,tout(end-1),yout(end-1)) + 1/3*step*feval(FunFcn, t, yn0) -yn0 + yout(end-1));
        ynf = yn0;
        yn0 = yn;
        iter = iter + 1;
    end
    y = yn;
    tout = [tout; t];
    yout = [yout; y.'];
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `fsolve` to short-cut solving the implicit equation without explicitly coding a Newton method gives the following implementation

```
function [T, Y] = multistep(FunFcn,t0,tfinal,step,y0)
  % initialize arrays
  N = 1;
  T = [ t0 ];
  Y = [ y0 ];
  F = [ FunFcn(t0, y0) ];

  % perform an RK3 step to have initial error O(h^4)
  % to get the requisite two samples to start the multistep method,
  % or use RK4 to stay with the O(h^5) local error
  N = N+1;
  T(N) = T(N-1)+step;
  Y(N,:) = RK3step(FunFcn,T(N-1),step,Y(N-1,:));
  F(N,:) = FunFcn(T(N), Y(N,:));

  % set error tolerances for implicit solver, 
  % the implicit error (times step size) should 
  % contribute less than the discretization error
  options = optimset("TolX", 1e-3*step^4, "TolFun", 1e-6*step^4);

  % main loop
  while abs(T(N)+0.6*step - tfinal) > 0.501*step 
    N = N+1;
    T(N) = T(N-1)+step ;
    % perform the multi-step method
    % y2 -y0 = h/3*(f0+4*f1+f2)
    % y2 - h/3*f(t2,y2) = b = y0 + h/3*(f0+4*f1)
    b = Y(N-2,:) + step/3*(F(N-2,:)+4*F(N-1,:));
    % solve the implicit equation using the built-in fsolve
    % Coding your own solver would allow a better management 
    % of the Jacobian approximation
    correct = @(y) ( y-step/3*FunFcn(T(N), y) - b );
    % predict = Y(N-2,:)+2*step*F(N-1,:);
    % use a 4th order predictor
    predict = 5*Y(N-2,:)-4*Y(N-1,:)+2*step*(2*F(N-1,:)+F(N-2,:));
    Y(N,:) = fsolve(correct, predict, options );
    F(N,:) = FunFcn(T(N), Y(N,:));
  end

  % Now tfinal is between T(N) + 0.1*step and T(N)+1.1*step
  % compute the final value with an RK3 step to add no more than an O(h^4) error
  N = N+1;
  T(N) = tfinal;
  Y(N,:) = RK3step(FunFcn,T(N-1),T(N)-T(N-1), Y(N-1,:));
end
```

Using `RK3` to handle the first and last steps is the minimum required, it is probably better to use `RK4` to have the error contributions negligible against the global error order 4.

The Runge-Kutta step functions implement the well-known methods:

```
function y1=RK3step(FunFcn, t0, step, y0)
  k1 = step*FunFcn(t0,y0);
  k2 = step*FunFcn(t0+0.5*step, y0+0.5*k1);
  k3 = step*FunFcn(t0+    step, y0+2*k2-k1);
  y1 = y0 + (k1+4*k2+k3)/6;
end

function y1=RK4step(FunFcn, t0, step, y0)
  k1 = step*FunFcn(t0         , y0       );
  k2 = step*FunFcn(t0+0.5*step, y0+0.5*k1);
  k3 = step*FunFcn(t0+0.5*step, y0+0.5*k2);
  k4 = step*FunFcn(t0+    step, y0+    k3);
  y1 = y0 + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6;
end
```

Now test the error order on a problem with known exact solution

```
%% test problem y''+sin(y) = r = p''+sin(p), y(0)=p(0), y'(0)=p'(0)
%% p=sin(t), p(0)=0, p'(0)=1, r(t)=-sin(t)+sin(sin(t))

TestODE = @(t,u) [ u(2), -sin(u(1))-sin(t)+sin(sin(t)) ];

t0 = 0; tf = 2;
[ T, Y ] = multistep(TestODE, t0,tf,0.2, [ 0, 1 ]);

printf("values found y1(1)=%.15f, y2(1)=%15f\n", Y(end,1), Y(end,2));
printf("exact values y1(1)=%.15f, y2(1)=%15f\n", sin(tf)  , cos(tf)  );
figure(1);
plot(Y(:,1), Y(:,2));
```

And to confirm the order, logarithmically plot the error against the step size

```
H = 0.1.^[1:0.5:3];
E1=[]; E2=[];
for h = H
  [ T, Y ] = multistep(@(t,u)TestODE(t,u),t0,tf,h,[ 0, 1 ]);
  E1(end+1) = max(abs( Y(:,1)'-sin(T) ));
  E2(end+1) = max(abs( Y(:,2)'-cos(T) ));
end
figure(2)
loglog(H,E1,H,E2)
end
```

[image: plots of solution and error]

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your elaborative input ! I faced some difficulties inputing functions. I added my own attempt at a code, which despite working and providing very good approximations for solutions, it seems to be of order $1$ and not $4$ as it should be, which troubles me a lot. Would you mind taking a look

Comment: It might be that the last step is the problem here. You could compute the error leaving out the last values. The method is only exact when the interval length is an integer multiple of `step`.

Comment: Appreciate the input to start off. I am solving the ODE : $y' = \frac{t^2+y^2}{2ty}$ over the interval $[1,3]$ with $y(1) = 2$. Then, by the directions of the exercise, I should make a step $h = 2^{-k}$ and the fraction of the maximum consecutive  absolute errors for each $h$should tend to $2^{-p}$ where $p$ is the order of the method, thus $1/16$. Using my code, I all of the values of the fractions yielded **indeed** tend to $1/16$ **BUT** the last one for $h=2^{-9}$ and $h=2^{-10}$ all of a sudden is $0.24$. How is that explained ? Or is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Your error tolerance for the Newton method is `tolnr   = 1e-9`, the global error in general can not be smaller than that. Reduce that proportional to $h^4$ to get an adapted error tolerance. // It should be sufficient to compute the derivative approximation once per integration step. The simplified Newton method has then a contraction quotient of $O(h^2)$. If you use the Euler step as predictor, the Newton iterates will then have errors $O(h^2), ~ O(h^4), ~ O(h^6)$ and the last one is in general accurate enough.

Comment: Great elaboration, thanks ! I can safely say I wasn't aware of these small details. I tried lowering the tolerances in general and that last term became lower, so I see what you meant in practice as well ! A TON of thanks for all the dedication to the post and the great answer ( I will work over your code and implement it as well ). Merry Christmas !

Comment: @Rebellos: Floating-point computation is nasty. You may be interested to read [What every computer scientist 'should' know about FP arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). I didn't know most of it before reading it. More relevant to your question is that you must ensure your machine error does not accumulate and end up bigger than the errors you are trying to measure.